# Was Triage X supposed to end after only 10 episodes?

Tags: triage-x

Was [*Triage X*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/26443/Triage_X) supposed to run for only 10 episodes? I could have sworn that when I first added this to my queue on MyAnimeList, it was listed to run for 12 episodes.

Did something happen (like lack of funding), or did I just misread the number and it was only going to run for 10 episodes all along?

Comment: I don't know anything about this particular situation, but I find it highly unlikely that a single-cour show (13 episodes or less) would be terminated prematurely for lack of funds - I just can't imagine that anyone could bungle the budget for a show _that_ badly.

Comment: It just seems off it was cutoff in the middle of a story, usually it seems the show would give an ending no matter how bad the ending may be. This just cuts off without any sort of closure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when I watched it, there were more episodes than episode 10.

Comment: There was an 11th episode bundled with one of the manga volumes, but that's it, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the following article on ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/daily-briefs/2015-03-20/triage-x-anime-listed-at-10-episodes/.86166) (dated 20 March, 2015, more than 2 weeks before the anime airs), it was confirmed that *Triage X* was listed at 10 episodes:

> A flyer at the AnimeJapan 2015 event's business day lists the television anime of Shoji Sato's Triage X manga as 10 episodes long, along with an original video animation (OVA) episode.

I also googled with queries such as `トリアージX 話数` and `トリアージX 全12話` (the second one is an attempt to dig out any article claiming 12 episodes), limited to articles posted before April, but all Japanese websites list the series at 10 episodes.

Since there is no evidence that the wrong information had been posted elsewhere on the Internet, it's probably due to MyAnimeList populating the wrong information, or a lapse in your memory.

Comment: Sweet it was probably a combination of me forgetting and MyAnimeList having the wrong info lol.